# How to pass enctype to simpleform in admin-on-rest?

Tags: reactjs, admin-on-rest

I am using admin-on-rest. I want to build file upload functionality using simpleform component of [admin-on-rest](https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest) framework.

For this, I want to pass **`enctype="multipart/form-data"`** to form.

I am not able find any documentation or forums to understand, how can I pass this, if inside any props, or some other way.

Please help with this.

Below is my code snippet:

```
<Create {...props}>
    <SimpleForm enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <FileInput source="files" label="Related files" multiple accept="text/*,image/*">
            <FileField source="src" title="title" />
        </FileInput>
    </SimpleForm>
</Create>
```